# Can we find exotic energy from outer space which is several times powerful than nuclear energy?If antimatter how?

Tags: energy, cosmology, exotic-matter

Some thing Like we see in sci fi films

Comment: What about a hydrogen bomb is not powerful enough for you? Seriously... :-)

Comment: An antimatter bomb would be 1000 times more powerful;-) Is antimatter exotic?

Comment: It would also be trillions of times more expensive. You might as well dig the hole it would make with a teaspoon, in terms of economics. A conventional nuclear weapon is dirt cheap. Not sure where you got the idea that dark energy is matter, anyway, or that it's dense, or somehow related to antimatter. None of that.

Comment: The same place you got hydrogen related to dark energy. I didn't say it was.

Comment: Neither did I. I merely asked the OP what's not to like about the super? When it goes off, the lights go out, and it's dirt cheap. The materials to build one are probably on the order of a few hundred k$.

Comment: Sorry. Thought it was a reply to me. Yep fusion is cheap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently we do not have enough knowledge/understanding on the workings of Dark Energy or Dark Matter to come to a satisfying conclusion that answers your question but for now, the substance that can create the biggest boom with the least amount of it is AntiMatter. An Antimatter - Matter annihilation bomb would create a very big explosion of pure energy, way bigger than what Nuclear Fusion or Fission can ever achieve. Maybe next time we might find more exotic forms of Matter and manipulate it enough to create a bomb that you proposed.

Comment: Well the Energy sources in Science-Fiction range from the Plausible to the Impossible. With enough knowledge of Physics, some things we now call impossible may indeed be possible. However power sources like the Tesseract which seemingly can manipulate immense quanta field, may be possible but these are all highly speculative. I feel that these may not be possible if these sources create energy out of nothing. (Violation of 2nd Law of Thermodynamics)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Antimatter exists in our galaxy in giant 100 light year wide plumes above the black hole in it's center.

Yes. If you could collect   the antimatter it would produce a 1000 times more energy per kilo than the nuclear fusion of the H bomb.

(The fusion of the H bomb is also 1000 times the energy of the fission of the A bomb)

Yes. A recent paper was written by Geraint Lewis on using the negative energy density of dark energy to create a warp drive.